# Accessing data from url in real time search using Reactjs and ajax

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am new to javascript and am working on a real time search app where I am using react to get the search results.
I am using ajax to get the data from a url as I had to use jsonp to get around server constraint. Although I am able to get the result in console.log in my searchForTerm function but not in render function as I am unable to bind it to my variable there properly. So I am unable to get the result that I want on screen.

Please check my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49367/)

Here is my code:

```
// var test = {};
// var json = {"F": {"symbol": "F", "name": "Ford Motor", "bidPrice": 13.43, "askPrice": 13.52}};
// test.data = [json];
// If i use the above variable and feed them to data during initialization,
// then it works. But when i get the same data from server i am not able to
// get the same update on my screen.


var SearchStock = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {searchString: '', data: [], quantity: ''};
    },

    componentWillMount: function() {
        // Get the initial terms
        this.doSearch();
    },

    componentWillUnmount: function() {
        this.serverRequest.abort();
    },

    doSearch: function(term) {
        this.serverRequest = this.searchForTerm(term || '').then(this.handleSearchResult);
    },

    searchForTerm: function (term) {
    var url = 'http://data.benzinga.com/rest/richquoteDelayed?symbols=' + term;
    return $.ajax({
        url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("in search", JSON.stringify(data));
            this.setState({data: [JSON.stringify(data)]});
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },

    handleSearchResult: function(quote) {
        this.setState(quote);
    },

    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({searchString: e.target.value});

        // The server doesn't seem to respond to lowercase values
        this.doSearch(e.target.value.toUpperCase());
    },

    buy: function(e){
        if(!term.quantity){
            term.quantity = e;
        } else {
            term.quantity = term.quantity + e;
        }
        return term.quantity;
    },

    sell: function(e){
        term.quantity = term.quantity - e;
        return term.quantity;
    },

    viewStock: function(e){
        searchForTerm(e);
    },

    render: function() {
        var stocks = this.state.data;
        console.log("in render", stocks);

        var searchString = this.state.searchString.trim().toLowerCase();

        if (searchString.length > 0) {
            stocks = stocks.filter(function(l) {
                // return l.name.toLowerCase().match(searchString);
                return l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["symbol"].toLowerCase().match(searchString);
            });
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div id='searchResult'>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.searchString} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Type here" />
                    <ul>
                        {stocks.map(function(l) {
                            return <div>
                                <h3>{l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["name"]}</h3>
                                <table class="table  table-striped table-bordered">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Bid</th>
                                        <th>Ask</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["bidPrice"]}</td>
                                        <td>{l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["askPrice"]}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        })}
                    </ul>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state.quantity} placeholder="Quantity" />
                    <input type="button" value="Buy" onClick={this.buy} />
                    <input type="button" value="Sell" onClick={this.sell} />
                </div>
                <div id='currentPorfolio'>
                    <h5>Current Portfolio</h5>
                    <h5>$100,000 This needs a disabled text box with value comming from a variable with initial value as $100000</h5>
                    <table class="table  table-striped table-bordered">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Company</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                            <th>Price Paid</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        {stocks.map(function(l) {
                            return <tr>
                                <td>{l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["name"]}</td>
                                <td>{l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["quantity"]}</td>
                                <td>{l[Object.keys(l)[0]]["bidPrice"]}</td>
                                <td>{<input type="button" value="View Stock"/>}</td>
                            </tr>
                        })}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render( <SearchStock />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I feel this should be related to scope of variables and the way they are being updated. But i would appreciate if anyone can help me out here as I can see the results in console log but not on the screen.

I have to work on debouncing too after this as right now this is sending requests to the server even when there is no change. Is there any better way to use handleChange to call only when there is a change in text box?

Apologies if I am missing something here as I am fairly new to javascript and react. And I have always been confused with the way javascript deals with scoping.

Comment: I get 'blocked: mixed content' for the AJAX call if I try to run your fiddle. Are you saying that you see the new data from `console.log("in render", stocks);` (so everything is working) but the DOM doesn't update? Try putting something simple like `<h1>Stocks: {this.state.stocks.length}</h1>`. Does that update?

Comment: @DavidGilbertson My Apologies, i meant that i can see the data in `console.log("in search", JSON.stringify(data));`, but not in render. Whereas the data in search that i am getting is the similar data as in var json. I have updated my post and fiddle to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah OK, I'm not sure what 'this' would be referring to inside jQuery's `ajax()`, I'll take a look...

Comment: @DavidGilbertson Thanks, it might be the problem. I am really not good with javascript variable scopes. I was just following reactjs tutorial and they had referred the variables in this way so i just followed that. But i don't think they used ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work it out with onBlur instead of onChange in react. Here is an article that i referred and helps us understand the difference in javascripts onchange() and reacts onChange() property and how onBlur() in react is equivalent to onchange() of javascript.

[How to "onchange" in ReactJS](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/onchange-in-reactjs)

I hope this helps someone who was confused between the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems here, the first one might be that `this` does not refer to the React component within jQuery's `ajax()` method (I can't tell because the URL doesn't work for me).

Try this, which will give you a reference to setState from outside the jQuery code.

```
searchForTerm: function (term) {
    const setState = state => this.setState(state);
    var url = 'http://data.benzinga.com/rest/richquoteDelayed?symbols=' + term;
    return $.ajax({
    url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {// your code here
        console.log("in search", JSON.stringify(data));
        setState({data: [JSON.stringify(data)]});
        }.bind(this)
    });
},
```

If this doesn't help, I would suggest fixing all the errors showing in the console, or removing all the code that causes them (for the example). It will be easier for others to help if there is a simple example of something not working as you expect.

Another issue you'll run into is that variables are scoped to the functions where they are defined. Thus in `buy()` and `sell()`, `term` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry i didn't check your answer before. It seems its a debouncing issue. As i am able to get the value in render too now, i just needed to use `JSON.stringify()` as i was getting json objects. But its sending new requests even after getting the data and nothing is displayed on screen.So i need to set a condition in handleChange where the ajax request is only sent when there is a change in textbox. Here is an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49386/).

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, i would appreciate i can find a way to stop the app from sending request after any change in textbox. And `buy` and `sell` are functions for future, so right now i am not bothered, but thanks for telling me about that. Sorry for making it difficult to go through it.